# Github actions: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. (Selenium | Python)

Tags: python, selenium, github-actions

I am working on windows machine. At the moment I am trying to run Selenium test using Github Actions on ubuntu-latest. Here is the code:

```
name: Selenium Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.9"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install software
      run: sudo apt-get -qqy install google-chrome-stable
    - name: version
      run: chromium-browser -version
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - name: Install selenium
      run: |
        pip install selenium
    - name: Webdriver-manager
      run: |
        pip install webdriver-manager
    - name: Run Create Project test
      run: |
        python CreateProjects/Run.py
```

However, I get an error "Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.".

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 101.0.4951
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 101.0.4951 google-chrome
[WDM] - There is no [linux64] chromedriver for browser 101.0.4951 in cache
[WDM] - About to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[WDM] - Driver has been saved in cache [/home/runner/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/101.0.4951.41]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/uwork/uwork/CreateProjects/Run.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Project() as pr:
  File "/home/runner/work/uwork/uwork/CreateProjects/Project/Project.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s, options=options)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I tried to add chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") to my python script, code seems to be running but does not click any elements (plus, test runs much longer).

```
class Project:
    def __init__(self, teardown = False):
        self.teardown = teardown
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s, chrome_options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get(const.BASE_URL)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

Using windows-latest everything works completely fine. How can I run selenium tests using ubuntu-latest? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try adding `chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')` ?

Comment: @ZoranPandovski, yes, I did.